# Active record includes with STI is not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I have following models:

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
end

class Employer < User
  has_many :jobs
  has_one :profile
end

class JobSeeker < User
end

class Profile < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :employer
end

class Job < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :employer
end
```

There is a verified attribute on profile of employer. I need to get list of job which have verified profile of employer. For this i tried:

```
Job.includes(employer: :profile).where(profiles: {verified: true})
```

But this is giving me error

> Job::ActiveRecord_Relation:0x3ff5d9d4a878

i am not getting what is wrong. Thank you in advance